# How do I join two files, and keep the non-matching lines?

Tags: python, unix, join

How can I merge two files, and keep non-matching lines?

My first file looks like this:

```
apples          1.4       
grapes          1.3
pears           2.1
oranges         1.1
grapefruit      1.0
```

My second file looks like this:

```
apples         Alex
grapes         Margery
grapefruit     Francis
```

My output should be:

```
apples          1.4     Alex  
grapes          1.3     Margery
pears           2.1
oranges         1.1
grapefruit      1.0     Francis
```

Any help with this would be most appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here. StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: Where have you got to yourself? Where's your code? What part has you stuck?

Comment: I have tried various things such as paste and join (i.e. join -o 1.1 1.2 2.1 2.2 <(cat -n file1) <(cat -n file2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use dataframes in pandas to do this. Convert you inputs to dataframes say a and b.

```
 import pandas as pd
```

Dataframe a

```
           x    y
 0      apples  1.4
 1      grapes  1.3
 2       pears  2.1
 3     oranges  1.1
 4  grapefruit  1.0
```

Dataframe b

```
        k        l
 0  apples     Alex
 1  grapes  Margery
 2   pears  Francis
```

Now rename the column with fruit names if they are different.

```
 b.columns=['x','l']
```

Then merge on the columname

```
new=pd.merge(a, b, on='x', how='outer')
```

Your new dataframe looks like this

```
           x    y        l
 0      apples  1.4     Alex
 1      grapes  1.3  Margery
 2       pears  2.1  Francis
 3     oranges  1.1      NaN
 4  grapefruit  1.0      NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (not tested) solution to your problem, given that there are no entries in file 2, that is not present in file 1:

```
import re

names = {}

with open("second.txt") as second:
    for line in second:
        m = match("([^\s]*)\s*([^\s]*)", line.strip())
        if m:
            names[m.group(1)] = m.group(2)

with open("first.txt") as first, open("output.txt", w) as out:
    for line in first:
        writeline = line
        m = match("([\s]*).*)", line.strip())
        if m:
            name = names.get(m.group(1), None)
            if name:
                writeline += "     " + name
        out.write(writeline)
```

What I am doing, is first parse second file, reading all the fruits and corresponding names into a dictionary. Then going through the first file, I check the fruit on each row for a corresponding entry in the dictionary, and if found that name is added to the output.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you can do something like:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$1]=$2; next}         # read first file and construct array
       $1 in seen{seen[$1]=seen[$1] OFS $2} # add entry from second file
       END{ for (e in seen) print e, seen[e]}' file1 file2
apples 1.4 Alex
grapefruit 1.0 Francis
oranges 1.1
pears 2.1
grapes 1.3 Margery
```

The order will change from the original file, but that was not stated as a requirement.

If you want the same order and the original file, and closer to your example, you might do:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
       FNR==NR{ord[FNR]=$1
               seen[$1]=$2
               next}
       $1 in seen {seen[$1]=seen[$1] OFS $2}
       END{ for (i=1;i in ord;i++)
               printf "%-10s\t%s\n", ord[i], seen[ord[i]]}' f1 f2
apples      1.4 Alex
grapes      1.3 Margery
pears       2.1
oranges     1.1
grapefruit  1.0 Francis
```